# Issue with sorting jquery datatables

Tags: javascript, jquery, datatables

It appears to sort fine at first glance, for example it sorts from 2019 dates all the way to 2020, then goes back to 2019 and on wards. (Date format DD/MM/YYYY). Have included the script and the table code below. Can someone help?

My code is as follows...

```html
     <script type="text/javascript">
                $(document).ready(function () {
                jQuery.extend( jQuery.fn.dataTableExt.oSort, {
                "date-uk-pre": function ( a ) {
                    var ukDatea = a.split('/');
                    return (ukDatea[2] + ukDatea[1] + ukDatea[0]) * 1;
                },
        
                "date-uk-asc": function ( a, b ) {
                    return ((a < b) ? -1 : ((a > b) ? 1 : 0));
                },
        
                "date-uk-desc": function ( a, b ) {
                    return ((a < b) ? 1 : ((a > b) ? -1 : 0));
                }
                } );
        
                    $('#tbl').DataTable({
                        stateSave: true,
                        order: [[9, 'asc']],
                        "aoColumns": [
                            null,
                            null,
                            null,
                            null,
                           {  "bSortable": false },
                            { "sType": "date-uk" },  //THIS IS THE ITEM I CLICK THE SORT BUTTON ON.
                            null,
                            null,
                            null,
                            { "sType": "date-uk" },
                             { "sType": "date-uk" },
                            null],
                      paging: false, "oLanguage": {
                        "sEmptyTable": "",
                        "sSearch": ""
                    }
                    });
        </script>

// Table code

    <table class="table  table-bordered" id="tbl">
    <thead>
        <tr>
            
            <th>
               Test Date sort 
            </th>
    
        </tr>
    </thead>

<tbody>
        <td>
            @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.TestDate)
        </td>

</tbody>
</table>
```

Comment: Please share a [mcve].

Comment: Sorting on a DD/MM/YYYY is going to give you troubles anyway. You'd better sort on timestamp or YYYY/MM/DD

Comment: There are many questions on SO about how to sort dates and datetimes in DataTables. Two possible answers are: (1) Use `moment.js` - for example, as shown [here](https://datatables.net/blog/2014-12-18); or (2) use [orthogonal data](https://datatables.net/manual/data/orthogonal-data) which lets you store different versions of a piece of data (e.g. "25/12/2020" for display purposes, but "20201225" for sorting purposes).

Comment: There's only one cell and one row; sorting's not going to do much.

Answer (score 0):

Thanks for all inputs, here's the solution:

Changed date format to:

```
@Convert.ToDateTime(item.TestDate).ToString("yyyy/MM/dd")
```

Instead of dd/mm/yyyy. Then removed the following code from the jquery:

```
//jQuery.extend( jQuery.fn.dataTableExt.oSort, {
//"date-uk-pre": function ( a ) {
//    var ukDatea = a.split('/');
//    return (ukDatea[2] + ukDatea[1] + ukDatea[0]) * 1;
//},

//"date-uk-asc": function ( a, b ) {
//    return ((a < b) ? -1 : ((a > b) ? 1 : 0));
//},

//"date-uk-desc": function ( a, b ) {
//    return ((a < b) ? 1 : ((a > b) ? -1 : 0));
//}
//} );
```